# Recycler view skipping layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have attached an adapter for `RecyclerView`
So why do I keep getting this error?

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getContext(),imageModelArrayList,ImageFragment.this);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
                            imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    });
```

ERROR LOGCAT

```
 E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
 E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Answer (score 0):

it happens when you are not setting the adapter during the creation phase and in your case, you did it after delay
so try to set adapter in your onCreate method like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
 imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getContext(),imageModelArrayList,ImageFragment.this);
recyclerView.setLayout(your layout);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
}
```

but if Fragment, calling the code from inside a ResultCallback method produces the same message. After moving the code to the onConnected() method within my app, the message was gone...

or you can fix it in XML like:

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lastTransactionRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"       

app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" // add this in 
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnTransactionMenuBack"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recycler_view_item_expense" />
```

Comment: im new in coding can you please help me more

Comment: after on `OnCreate` Method